# Recommended design pattern(s) to use

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

Suppose I have very basic **Task** class as follows:

```
public class Task
{
    string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add Planning "behaviour" to **SOME** of my tasks. Obviously I will have to have something like:

```
public interface IPlannable
{
    public void CalculatePlan();
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime Finish { get; }
}
```

and two concrete algorithms, each with different input parameters:

```
public class PlanStrategyA : IPlannable
{
    private int parameter1;
    private int parameter2;
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime finish;

    public PlanStrategyA(int p1, int p2)
    {
        parameter1 = p1;
        parameter2 = p2;
    }

    public void CalculatePlan()
    {
        // ... uses parameter1 & parameter2
        // ... to calculate start and finish
    }

    public DateTime Start { get { return this.start; } }

    public DateTime Finish { get { return this.finish; } }
}

public class PlanStrategyB : IPlannable
{
    public int parameter3;

    // ... the rest is similar to PlanningStrategyA

}
```

Question is :

What is **best design pattern** to use to connect base Task class to concrete Planning strategy as OPTION, meaning that not all Tasks is required to be planned, ie. to have Planning behaviour ?

User should have possibility to "promote" task to be planned, and also to "remove" this behaviour from particular task.

How all this applies to persisting to Database via EF, or other ORM, particularly when reading from database ? What pattern will best fit reading from DB and creating back my task objects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have 2 distinct issues here.
One is the strategy algorithm for plannable tasks - you can use a [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for handling this.
Regarding the tasks that aren't plannable, I see 2 possible approaches:

1. Exclude it from scope of design pattern. It's perfectly ok, patterns shouldn't be forced upon your design if not needed.
2. Have a 2-level strategy - upper level to choose whether task is plannable or not and lower level (for plannable only) to apply your strategy.

The other one is a set of possible behaviors for each task. This can be tackled with [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). No behavior is also a behavior.

Comment: thanks for answwer. I supposed so, but it is still not clear to me what to do if task is not required to be planned. If i will have variable in class Task like:

`private IPlannable p;`

should I just keep at as null (not instantiated) when task won't be planned, or is it better to have "dummy" concrete strategy with no additional parameters, and with empty `CalculatePlan()` method ?

Comment: I've added to the answer

Comment: do you mean in your alt (1) that I should have base Task class as it is shown, and inherit from it `class PlannableTask : Task` with additional variable IPlannable ? I don't think it is good approach ?

Comment: Well, your plannable task **is a** `Task` with all its properties, so I think it should inherit from `Task` and also implement the `IPlannable` interface.

Comment: `Plannable` task **is a** `Task`, yes. But if `Plannable` is only one of optional behaviour each of task could have, what then. If there are more behaviours like `Saleable`, `Trackable`, `Deliverable`, etc. and if all this behaviours are optional, I will end in huge number of inherited classes for each possible combination, which is, I suppose, not good. As far as I understand I should implement **COMPOSITION** is some form, and make each task as composition of optional behaviours, but then, as I mentioned, I'm not sure what to do if task does not have particular behaviour...

Comment: Ah, seems like I didn't read the question thoroughly. I agree with you aobut composition and added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks @icepack for additional info. I was thinking about COMPOSITION, which is, as I understand, not pattern by itself, but is used in some patterns. So far, I don't see how *Composite pattern* could help. As I know it is intended to represent part-of-a-whole, with main goal to access *whole* on the same way as *part*. If you could put some short code example how you see it helps here, it would be great :-)

Comment: I reposted extended question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13504199/1255664)!