# Strategy Pattern with Dummy concrete strategy

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Refering to posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13503015/1255664), could you please comment if this is good approach to solve OPTIONAL behaviour for extending class, by using composition, not inheritance. `Plannable` behaviour is here extended by Strategy pattern.

So, class `Task` could optionally have any combination of various behaviours. `Plannable` is just one of them, therefore inheritance does obviously not making sense here.

Question is what to do when Task does not have particular behaviour ? I see few possible approaches:

1. Instantiate concrete strategy for each task, and implement "Dummy" strategy when `Task` is not `Plannable` (this alternative is shown below). There are weird nullable `Start` and `Finish` variables all over the code, in this case...
2. Having `nullable` IPlanningStrategy variable in the case task won't be planned, and instantiate with concrete Strategy only when it is "promoted" to be `Plannable`.

Alternative (1) should be something like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private IPlanningStrategy planningStrategy;

    public Task()
    {
        planningStrategy = new NoPlanStrategy();
    }

    public Task(IPlanningStrategy initialPlanningStrategy)
    {
        planningStrategy = initialPlanningStrategy;
    }

    public void SetPlanningStrategy(IPlanningStrategy newPlanningStrategy)
    {
        planningStrategy = newPlanningStrategy;
    }

    public DateTime? Start { get { return planningStrategy.Start; } }
    public DateTime? Finish { get { return planningStrategy.Finish; } }
}


public interface IPlanningStrategy
{
    public void CalculatePlan();
    public DateTime? Start { get; }
    public DateTime? Finish { get; }
}

// "Dummy" strategy, used when Task does not have Planning behaviour
//
public class NoPlanStrategy : IPlanningStrategy
{
    public void CalculatePlan() { }
    public DateTime? Start { get { return null; } }
    public DateTime? Finish { get { return null; } }
}



public class PlanStrategyA : IPlanningStrategy
{
    private int parameter1;
    private int parameter2;
    private DateTime? start;
    private DateTime? finish;

    public PlanStrategyA(int p1, int p2)
    {
        parameter1 = p1;
        parameter2 = p2;
        start = finish = null;
    }

    public void CalculatePlan()
    {
        // ... uses parameter1 & parameter2
        // ... to calculate start and finish
    }

    public DateTime? Start { get { return start; } }

    public DateTime? Finish { get { return finish; } }
}

public class PlanStrategyB : IPlanningStrategy
{
    public int parameter3;

    // ... the rest is similar to PlanningStrategyA

}
```

Now I see different ** VERY IMPORTANT** problem here. Each of my concrete Strategy class holds, beside algorithm, which is of course shared for all tasks implementing this algorithm, additional parameters, which belongs only to particular `Task`.

You can imagine `parameter1` as `Effort` (or, say, number of remaining hours required to complete task), and say `parameter2` as `LastDate` (representing constraint date, ie. last allowable date to finish task). This parameters naturally belongs to particular `Task`, but only if it implements this particular `StrategyA`.

It seems that instantiate strategy outside `Task` class does not make sense ? Or this should be job for some `Factory` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you are exposing too much information in your `Task` class. I would do as follows:

```
public class Task
{
    // what is title being used for?
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private IPlanningStrategy planningStrategy;

    public Task(IPlanningStrategy initialPlanningStrategy)
    {
        // Initialize it outside of constructor
        if(initialPlanningStrategy == null)
        {  
           throw new NullArgumentException(); // or return. 
        }
        planningStrategy = initialPlanningStrategy;
    }

    public void CalculatePlan(){
        // check null and return.
        planningStrategy.CalculatePlan();
    }

}
```

Your client shouldnt know start, finish, i dont see that as responsibility of a container for algorithms.

Moreover, if your NoPlanStrategy not doing anything, why introduce it. removeit.

Comment: Thanks for answer. If it is OK to have nullable `Task.planninStrategy`, then, of course, I don't need "dummy" `NoStrategy` class, and can be removed. About your second point, my clients are really interested about `Start` and `Finish`, since whole Planning behaviour is all about show them `Start` and `Finish`, if `Task` is `Plannable`. But again, `Start` and `Finish` could be represented on similar way you done for `Task.CalculatePlan()`, ie. check for null and return `Start/Finish` if not null ?

Comment: yes you can do that, and if you need to return Start/Finish put them in an object, change ur interface to return whatever information your client expect for satisfying this contract. handle exceptions accordingly.

Comment: you need to rethink what you want to do. Read SOLID principles.

Comment: I m not familiar with your context, my answer was for Strategy pattern and its use etc.

Comment: I guess you're right. More homework for me, I accepted your answer :-)